# Elastic Search Index not analyzed

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search, and I'm having a hard time with the analyzers.

I am creating an index like this  (to replicate my problem, you can copy and paste the follwoing code in your console directly.)

Please read comments in the script for my problem and questions.

```
#!/bin/bash
# fails if the index doesn't exist but that's OK
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/movies/'

# creating the index that will allow type wrapper, and generate _id automatically from the path

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/movies -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "mapping.allow_type_wrapper" : true,
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "en_std": {
                    "type":"standard",
                    "stopwords": "_english_"
                }
            }
        }

    },
    "mappings" : {
        "movie" : {
            "_id" : {
                "path" : "movie.id"
            }
        }
    }
}'

# inserting some data
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/movies/movie -d '{
    "movie" : {
        "id" : 101,
        "title" : "Bat Man",
        "starring" : {
            "firstname" : "Christian",
            "lastname" : "Bale"
        }
    }
}'

#trying to get by ID ... \m/ works!!!
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/101


# tryign to search using query_string ... \m/ works
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "bat"
        }
    }
}'

# when i try to search in a paricular field it fails. returns 0 hits
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/movies/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "bat",
             "fields" : ["movie.title"]

        }
    }
}'


#I thought the analyzer was the problem, so i checked. 
curl 'http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
   "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "bat"

        }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "doc[field].values",
            "params": {
                "field": "movie.title"
            }
        }

    }
}'

# The field wasn't analyzed.
# the follwoing is the result
#{
#  "took" : 1,
#  "timed_out" : false,
#  "_shards" : {
#    "total" : 1,
#    "successful" : 1,
#    "failed" : 0
#  },
#  "hits" : {
#    "total" : 1,
#    "max_score" : 0.13424811,
#    "hits" : [ {
#      "_index" : "movies",
#      "_type" : "movie",
#      "_id" : "101",
#      "_score" : 0.13424811,
#      "fields" : {
#        "terms" : [ "Bat Man" ]
#      }
#    } ]
#  }
#}


# So i even tried the term as such... Nope didn't work :(  0 hits.
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/movies/_search -d '{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "Bat Man",
             "fields" : ["movie.title"]

        }
    }
}'
```

Can anyone point out what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ? also could you try running          `curl -Xget "http://localhost:9200/movies/_analyze?text=Bat Man"` to see how your default analyzer analyzes

Comment: Im running 0.90.11. And, Yes. Tried that. This one analyses it perfectly. Splits it into two lower case terms: bat, man. But the queries are not working

Answer (score 0):

You should insert a `sleep 1` command right after inserting the doc and everything will work.

Elasticsearch provides search in near real-time ([read this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh)). Everytime you index a document, the Lucene index is not updated (refreshed in terms of Elasticsearch) immediately. How frequently your index is refreshed is configurable on Index level. You can also forcefully refresh the index by passing the query parameter `refresh=true` with every HTTP request, which will make ES update the index. But you may start suffering on the performance because of that depending upon your requirement.

There is a [Refresh API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) as well.

Comment: No. I tried this. This isn't the problem. Gives zero hits even after a while.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to the latest version? Your script worked for me on 1.1.x version of ES.